# On click reset the background color to transparent in javascript of each div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

on-click my div element not changing its background color to transparent, as it changed before when

I have only one div element. each div elements background color should change to transparent on each click in the corresponding div.

I'm a newbie to scripting how to achieve it

```js
function myfunction()
{
var x = document.getElementById("001");
alert(document.write("x"));
x.addEventListener("click", vanish);
vanish();
function vanish()
{
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#x").click(function() {
    $("#x").css('background-color', 'none');
    $("#x").css('opacity', '0.0');
  });
});

}
```

```css
.box {
    background-color: coral;
    width: 30%;
 height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:5px;
 border:1px solid black;
 padding-left:0px;
}
.text {
    padding: 10px 0;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
#container {
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-align:center;
 margin-left:25%;
 margin-right:25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div class="box" id="001" onclick="myfunction()">
        <div class="text">text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="001" name="mybox" onclick="myfunction()">
        <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="001" name="mybox" onclick="myfunction()">
        <div class="text" id="003">Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Repeating ID is a very very common error. That's why is not working. Using Jquery you can solve this very easy. Just $('.box').click(function(){$(this).css({background:'transparent'})})

Comment: yeah i now understand thank for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `id` need to unique secondly `x.addEventListener("click"..` inside click handle is no more required.Also the `vanish` function is not required here and there is no necessity of document.ready and click inside that

```js
function myfunction(event) {
  $(event.target).css('background-color', 'none');
  $(event.target).css('opacity', '0.0');

}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: coral;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.text {
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="box" id="" onclick="myfunction(event)">
    <div class="text">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="" name="mybox" onclick="myfunction(event)">
    <div class="text">Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="" name="mybox" onclick="myfunction(event)">
    <div class="text" id="003">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Frankly, this is bad advice. There is no excuse for using the outdated `on*` event attributes any more, even less so when you're using jQuery. The other answer by @ZakariaAcharki is far better.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using jQuery it could be simply by attaching the click to the common class and use `$(this)` to refer to the current clicked element.

**NOTE:** The `id` should be unique in the same document, replace the duplicate ones.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".box").click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'none');
    $(this).css('opacity', '0.0');
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: coral;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.text {
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="box" id="001">
    <div class="text">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="002" name="mybox">
    <div class="text">Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="003" name="mybox">
    <div class="text" id="003">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```